# Test project не выполняет test case

Tags: c++, юнит-тесты, boost, cmake

Создал юнит-тест c помощью Boost Test.

main.cpp

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE MyTest
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( MyTest )
{
    BOOST_ERROR( "Ouch..." );           
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Создал CmakeFile.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(Test)
# Enable testing for the project
enable_testing()
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS        ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED      ON)


find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system filesystem unit_test_framework)

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable (Test main.cpp)

target_link_libraries (Test
        ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
        )


if(UNIX)
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} -pthread)
endif(UNIX)

# declares a test with our executable
add_test(NAME MyTest COMMAND Test)

> cd $test_path
> mkdir build     
> cd build
> cmake  ..       
> cmake --build . 
> ctest
```

Выдает:

```
Test project /home/ilya-/Tests/build
    Start 1: MyTest
1/1 Test #1: MyTest ...........................   Passed    0.00 sec

100% tests passed, 0 tests failed out of 1

Total Test time (real) =   0.00 sec
```

Почему нету ошибки?

Comment: А есть необходимость использовать буст? Если перейти на autotools то там на мой взгляд намного удобнее с тестами и меньше телодвижений. Уже не говоря о том что это стандартный инсталлер для большинства проектов..

Comment: У нас используется boost, поэтому я и решил с помощью его начать писать тесты, подобными вещами не занимался, поэтому хороших инструментов не знаю. За autotools спасибо, ознакомлюсь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо в теле после инклюда начать примерно так:

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(MyTest)
.... тут все ваши тесты с другими именами, чтоб не пересекались с Suite

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(MyTestOne)
{
    BOOST_ERROR( "Ouch..." );           
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()

int main()
{
```

И в `CMakeLists.txt` надо добавить:

```
add_definitions(-DBOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK)
set (TESTS MyTest) #MovableObjectTest)
enable_testing()
```

Запускать тест возможно с помощью `make test`